# Invalid resource name creating a connection to azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to create a project of the labeling tool from the Azure form recognizer. I have successfully deployed the web app, but I'm unable to start a project. I get this error all every time I try:

[image]

I have tried with several app instances and changing the project name and connection name, none of those work. The only common factor and finding here as that it is related to the connection.

As I see it:

1) I can either start a new project or use one on the cloud:

[image]

First I tried to create a new project:

I filled the fields with these values:

[image]

```
Display Name: Test-form
Source Connection: <previuosly created connection>
Folder Path: None
Form Recognizer Service Uri: https://XXX-test.cognitiveservices.azure.com/
API Key: XXXXX
Description: None
```

And got the error from the question's title:

`"Invalid resource name creating a connection to azure storage` "

I tried several combinations of names, none of those work.

Then I tried with the option: "Open a cloud project"

Got the same error instantly, hence I deduce the issue is with the connection settings.

Now, In the connection settings I have this:

[image]

At first glance, since the values are accepted and the connection is created. I guess it is correct but it is the only point I failure I can think of.

Regarding the storage container settings, I added the required CORS configuration and I have used it to train models with the Forms Recognizer, So that part does works.

At this point at pretty much stuck, since I error message does not give me many clues on where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar error today

You have to add container name before "?sv..." in your SAS URI in connection settings

```
https://****.blob.core.windows.net/**trainingdata**?sv=2019-10-10..
```